# zsh completion for gpg

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, gpg

I am using the default `_gpg` completion file for `zsh`, which came with my zsh version `5.7.1-1` (debian 10). I have pasted the file here: https://ctxt.io/2/AABg86pPFQ

When I do `gpg <TAB>`, zsh completes files and directories in current directory. I would like to change that, so that:

a) if I use gpg without further arguments (which implies `-d`), then only *.gpg files in current dir are completed (not directories)

b) if I use `-e` or `-c` (implies encryption), only non-gpg files in current directory are completed (not directories)

c) for the rest, I guess the default behavior is oK

I have added following to my `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:gpg:*' file-patterns '*.(gpg|sig)(.)'
```

but that should only be the rule for case a)

How can I achieve behavior described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never edited zsh completion files so there might be some bugs
but that does what you want:

```
#compdef gpg gpgv gpg-zip gpg2=gpg

local curcontext="$curcontext" state line expl ret=1
local -a args allopts dups extra
typeset -A opt_args

if [[ $service = gpg-zip ]]; then
  args=(
    '--gpg[command to use instead of gpg]:command:_command'
    '--gpg-args[gpg arguments]:gpg arguments:'
    '--tar[command to use instead of tar]:command:_command'
    '--tar-args[tar arguments]:tar arguments:'
    '--list-archive[list archive contents]'
  )
else
  allopts=( $(_call_program options $words[1] --dump-options) )
  args=(
    '(-q --quiet)*'{-v,--verbose}'[increase amount of output]'
    '(-q --quiet -v --verbose)'{-q,--quiet}'[reduce amount of output]'
    '--keyring=[add specified file to list of keyrings]:file:_files'
    '--'{status,logger}'-fd:file descriptor:_file_descriptors'
    '--homedir:directory:_directories'
  )
fi

[[ $service = gpgv ]] || args+=(
  '(-e --encrypt)'{-e,--encrypt}'[encrypt data. this option may be combined  with --sign]:files:_path_files -g "^(#i)*.gpg(-.)"'
  '(-d,--decrypt)'{-d,--decrypt}'[decrypt file or stdin]:files:_path_files -g "(#i)*.gpg(-.)"'
  '(-c --symmetric)'{-c,--symmetric}'[encrypt with symmetric cipher only]:files:_path_files -g "^(#i)*.gpg(-.)"'
  '(-s --sign)'{-s,--sign}'[make a signature]'
  '*'{-r+,--recipient}'[specify user to encrypt for]:recipient:->public-keys'
  '(-u --local-user)'{-u+,--local-user}'[use name as the user ID to sign]:user attachment:_users'
  '(-o --output)'{-o+,--output}'[write output to file]:output file:_files'
  '(-h --help)'{-h,--help}'[display usage information]'
  '--version[print info on program version and supported algorithms]'
  '*:filename _files:_path_files -g "(#i)*.gpg(-.)"'
)

[[ $service = gpg ]] && args+=(
  '--decrypt-files[decrypt multiple files]'
  '(-b --detach-sign)'{-b,--detach-sign}'[make a detached signature]'
  --clear{,-}sign'[make a clear text signature]'
  '--store[store only]'
  '--verify[verify a signature]'
  '--verify-files[verify a list of files]'
  '(-f --encrypt-files)'{-f,--encrypt-files}'[encrypt files]'
  '(-k --list-keys)'{-k,--list-keys}'[list all keys]'
  '--list-public-keys[list all public keys]'
  '(-K --list-secret-keys)'{-K,--list-secret-keys}'[list all secret keys]'
  --list-sig{,nature}s'[lists keys and signatures]:key attachment:->public-keys'
  '--list-options[modify what the various --list-* commands show]: :->option-list'
  --check-sig{,nature}s'[list key, signatures and check them]:key attachment:->public-keys'
  '--fingerprint[list all keys with their fingerprints]:key attachment:->public-keys'
  '--list-packets[list only the sequence of packets]'
  '--gen-key[generate a new pair key]'
  '--edit-key[interactively edit a key]:key attachment:->public-keys'
  '--sign-key[sign a key]:key attachment:->public-keys'
  '--lsign-key[sign a key but mark as non-exportable]:key attachment:->public-keys'
  '--delete-keys[remove key from public keyring]:key attachment:->public-keys'
  '--delete-secret-keys[remove key from public & private keyring]:key attachment:->secret-keys'
  '--delete-secret-and-public-keys:key attachment:->secret-keys'
  '--gen-revoke[generate a revocation certificate]'
  '--desig-revoke[generate a designated revocation certificate]'
  '--passwd[change a passphrase]'
  '--export[export all keys from all keyrings]'
  '--send-keys[send keys to a keyserver]:key attachment:->public-keyids'
  '--export-secret-keys:key attachment:->secret-keys'
  '--export-secret-subkeys:key attachment:->secret-keys'
  '--import[import a gpg key from a file]:attachment (file):_files'
  '--fast-import[import a file without adding to trustdb]:attachment (file):_files'
  '--fetch-keys[fetch key at URIs]:uri:'
  --rec{eive,v}-keys'[receive a list of keys from a keyserver]:key attachment:->public-keyids'
  '--refresh-keys[update all keys from a keyserver]'
  '--search-keys[search for keys on a key server]'
  '--update-trustdb[update the trust database]'
  '--check-trustdb[unattended trust database update]'
  '--fix-trustdb[fix a corrupted trust database]'
  '--export-ownertrust[list the assigned ownertrust values in ASCII format]:file:_files'
  '--import-ownertrust[update the trustdb with a file]:file:_files'
  '--dearmor[de-Armor a file or stdin]'
  '--enarmor[en-Armor a file or stdin]'
  '--print-md[print message digests]:algorithm:->ciphers::file:_files'
  '--print-mds[print message digests]::file:_files'
  '--tofu-policy:policy:(good unknown bad ask auto):*:keys:->public-keys'
  '--tofu-default-policy:policy:(good unknown bad ask auto)'
  '--quick-generate-key:user-id: :algorithm:(default future-default rsa dsa elg ed25519 cv25519): : _values -s , usage - default sign auth encr::expiration'
  '--quick-add-key:fingerprint: :algorithm:(default future-default rsa dsa elg ed25519 cv25519): : _values -s , usage - default sign auth encr::expiration'
  '--gen-random:quality level:(0 1 2):count (bytes)' '--gen-prime'
  '--warranty[print warranty info]'
  '(-a --armor)'{-a,--armor}'[create ASCII armored output]'
  '--default-key[specify default user ID for signatures]:key:->secret-keys'
  '--default-recipient[specify default recipient]:recipient:->public-keys'
  '--default-recipient-self[use default key as default recipient]'
  '--no-default-recipient[reset default recipient]'
  '*--encrypt-to[specify recipient]:key:->public-keys'
  '(--encrypt-to)--no-encrypt-to[disable the use of all --encrypt-to keys]'
  '-z[specify compression level]:compression level:((0\:no\ compression 1\:minimum 2 3 4 5 6\:default 7 8 9\:maximum))'
  '(-t --textmode)'{-t,--textmode}'[use canonical text mode]'
  '(-n --dry-run)'{-n,--dry-run}"[don't make any changes]"
  '(-i --interactive --batch)'{-i,--interactive}'[prompt before overwriting files]'
  '(-i --interactive --no-batch)--batch[use batch mode]'
  '--no-tty[never output to tty]'
  '(--batch)--no-batch[disable batch mode]'
  '(--no)--yes[assume "yes" on most questions]'
  '(--yes)--no[assume "no" on most questions]'
  '--default-cert-check-level:check level:((0\:no\ claim 1\:no\ verification 2\:casual\ verification 3\:extensive\ verification))'
  '--trusted-key[assume that the specified key is trustworthy]:long key id'
  '--always-trust[skip key validation]'
  '--keyserver[specify key server to use]:key server:_hosts'
  '--keyserver-options[specify keyserver options]:options'
  '--import-options[specify options for importing keys]:options'
  '--export-options[specify options for exporting keys]:options'
  '--photo-viewer:command:_command_names -e'
  '--exec-path:path:_dir_list'
  '--show-keyring[display keyring name when listing keys]'
  '--secret-keyring[add specified file to list of secret keyrings]:file:_files'
  '--charset:character set:(iso-8859-1 iso-8859-2 koi8-r utf-8)'
  '--utf8-strings' '--no-utf8-strings[arguments are not in UTF8]'
  '(--no-options)--options[specify file to read options from]:options file:_files'
  "(--options)--no-options[don't read options file]"
  '--'{attribute,passphrase,command}'-fd:file descriptor:_file_descriptors'
  '--sk-comments[include secret key comments when exporting keys]'
  '(--emit-version)--no-emit-version[omit version string in clear text signatures]'
  '(--no-emit-version)--emit-version[force writing of version string in clear text signatures]'
  '(-N --notation-data)'{-N,--notation-data}'[put parameter in signature]:name=value'
  '(--no-show-notation)--show-notation[show key signature notations]'
  "(--show-notation)--no-show-notation[don't show key signature notations]"
  '--set-policy-url:policy URL'
  '--set-filename[specify file which is stored in messages]:file:_files'
  '--completes-needed:number' '--marginals-needed:number' '--max-cert-depth:number'
  '--'{{,disable-,s2k-}cipher,{,s2k-,cert-}digest,disable-pubkey}'-algo:cipher:->ciphers'
  '--s2k-mode:value'
  '--compress-algo:compression algorithm:((0\:disable\ compression 1\:zlib 2\:rfc1950))'
  '--personal-'{cipher,digest,compress}'-preferences:string'
  --{card-edit,edit-card}'[present smartcard menu]' '--card-status[show smartcard content]'
  '--change-pin[present menu to change smartcard pin]'
  '--list-config[display internal configuration parameters]'
  '--hidden-recipient[hidden recipient]:recipient:->public-keys'
  '--default-preference-list:string'
  '--fetch-keys:URIs'
  '--hidden-encrypt-to:recipient:->public-keys'
  '--compress-level:integer'
  '--bzip2-compress-level:integer'
  '--default-cert-level:integer'
  '--max-output[maximum output generated when processing file]:bytes:'
  '--gpg-agent-info[override GPG_AGENT_INFO]:'
  '--primary-keyring:file:_files'
  '--verify-options: :->verify-options'
  '--debug:flags:' '--status-file:file:_files'
  '--attribute-file:file:_files' '--load-extension:file:_files'
  '--s2k-count:integer'
  '--sig-notation:name=value:' '--cert-notation:name=value:'
  '--passphrase-file:file:_files' '--passphrase-repeat:integer:'
  '--command-file:file:_files' '--trustdb-name:file:_files'
  '--trust-model:trust model:(pgp classic tofu tofu+pgp direct always auto)'
  '--sig-policy-url:string:' '--cert-policy-url:string:'
  '--sig-keyserver-url:string:' '--comment[comment]:comment:'
  '--no-comments[disable comments]'
  '--logger-file[write log to file]:file:_files'
  '--rebuild-keydb-caches[create signature caches in keyring]'
  '--default-keyserver-url:name:'
  '--display-charset[set native charset]:charset:((iso-8859-1 iso-8859-2 iso-8859-15 koi8-r utf-8))'
  '--ungroup[remove group]:group name:'
  '--no-groups[remove all entries from --group list]'
  '--enable-progress-filter[enable progress status output]'
  '--multifile[process multiple files]'
  '--keyid-format[key id format]:key format:((short 0xshort long 0xlong))'
  '--exit-on-status-write-error[exit immediately on error write]'
  '--limit-card-insert-tries:integer'
  '--reader-port[card reader port]:port'
  '--ctapi-driver[file to use to access smartcard reader]:file:_files'
  '--pcsc-driver[file to use to access smartcard reader]:file:_files'
  '--auto-key-locate:parameters'
  '--dump-options[show all options]'
)

extra=( ${${${args#\([^\)]#\)}#\*}%%[:=\[]*} )
extra=( ${allopts:|extra} )
_arguments -C -s -S -A "-*" $args $extra  && ret=0

if [[ $state = args ]]; then
  if (( ${+opt_args[--export]} || ${+opt_args[-k]} || ${+opt_args[--list-keys]} || ${+opt_args[--list-public-keys]} )); then
    state=public-keys
  elif (( ${+opt_args[--list-secret-keys]} )); then
    state=secret-keys
  else
    _files && return
  fi
fi

# We need to keep some arguments to get a consistent list of keys
# etc.
local -a needed
integer krind=${words[(I)--keyring(|=*)]}
needed=(${words[(r)--no-default-keyring]})
if (( krind )); then
  # We have a --keyring option.  We can't be completing its
  # argument because that was handled above, so it must be complete.
  if [[ $words[krind] = --keyring ]]; then
    if [[ -n $words[krind+1] ]]; then
      needed+=(--keyring=$words[krind+1])
    fi
  else
    needed+=($words[krind])
  fi
fi

case "$state" in
  public-keys)
    local public_keys_lines=(${(f)"$(_call_program public-keys ${(q)words[1]} ${(q)needed} --list-public-keys --list-options no-show-photos --with-colons)"})
    local -a uids emails
    local i j parts current_uid
    for (( i = 1; i < ${#public_keys_lines[@]}; ++i )); do
      parts=("${(@s.:.)public_keys_lines[$i]}")
      if [[ ${parts[1]} == "fpr" ]]; then
        current_uid="${parts[10]}"
        i=$((i + 1))
        parts=("${(@s.:.)public_keys_lines[$i]}")
        while [[ ${parts[1]} == "uid" ]]; do
          uids+=("${current_uid}")
          emails+=("${parts[10]}")
          i=$((i + 1))
          parts=("${(@s.:.)public_keys_lines[$i]}")
        done
      fi
    done
    _describe -t public-keys 'public key' emails uids
  ;;
  secret-keys)
    local secret_keys_lines=(${(f)"$(_call_program secret-keys ${(q)words[1]} ${(q)needed} --list-secret-keys --list-options no-show-photos --with-colons)"})
    local -a uids emails
    local i j parts current_uid
    for (( i = 1; i < ${#secret_keys_lines[@]}; ++i )); do
      parts=("${(@s.:.)secret_keys_lines[$i]}")
      if [[ ${parts[1]} == "fpr" ]]; then
        current_uid="${parts[10]}"
        i=$((i + 1))
        parts=("${(@s.:.)secret_keys_lines[$i]}")
        while [[ ${parts[1]} == "uid" ]]; do
          uids+=("${current_uid}")
          emails+=("${parts[10]}")
          i=$((i + 1))
          parts=("${(@s.:.)secret_keys_lines[$i]}")
        done
      fi
    done
    _describe -t secret-keys 'secret key' emails uids
  ;;
  ciphers)
    _wanted ciphers expl cipher compadd \
        ${${(s.,.)${(M)${(f)${"$(_call_program ciphers ${(q)words[1]} ${(q)needed} --version)"}//,$'\n' #/, }:#Cipher*}#*:}# } && return
  ;;
  (public-keyids)
    local public_keys_lines=(${(f)"$(_call_program public-keyids ${(q)words[1]} ${(q)needed} --list-public-keys --list-options no-show-photos --with-colons)"})
    local -a uids emails
    local i j parts current_uid
    for (( i = 1; i < ${#public_keys_lines[@]}; ++i )); do
      parts=("${(@s.:.)public_keys_lines[$i]}")
      if [[ ${parts[1]} == "fpr" ]]; then
        current_uid="${parts[10]}"
        i=$((i + 1))
        parts=("${(@s.:.)public_keys_lines[$i]}")
        while [[ ${parts[1]} == "uid" ]]; do
          uids+=("${current_uid}")
          emails+=("${parts[10]}")
          i=$((i + 1))
          parts=("${(@s.:.)public_keys_lines[$i]}")
        done
      fi
    done
    _describe -t public-keyids 'public key' emails uids
  ;;
  (option-list)
    _sequence _wanted options expl option \
        compadd - {no-,}show-{photos,usage,policy-urls,{std,user}-notations,keyserver-urls,uid-validity,unusable-{uids,subkeys},keyring,sig-{expire,subpackets}} && return
  ;;
  (verify-options)
    _sequence _wanted options expl option \
        compadd - {no-,}show-{photos,policy-urls,{std,user}-notations,keyserver-urls,uid-validity,unusable-uids,primary-uid-only} {no-,}pka-{lookups,trust-increase} && return
  ;;
esac

return ret
```

The file is huge so it's hard to notice what was changed at the first
glance so you can use `diff` tool to quickly see:

```
$ diff /usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions/_gpg /usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions/_gpg.bak
27,29c27,29
<   '(-e --encrypt)'{-e,--encrypt}'[encrypt data. this option may be combined  with --sign]:files:_path_files -g "^(#i)*.gpg(-.)"'
<   '(-d,--decrypt)'{-d,--decrypt}'[decrypt file or stdin]:files:_path_files -g "(#i)*.gpg(-.)"'
<   '(-c --symmetric)'{-c,--symmetric}'[encrypt with symmetric cipher only]:files:_path_files -g "^(#i)*.gpg(-.)"'
---
>   '(-e --encrypt)'{-e,--encrypt}'[encrypt data. this option may be combined  with --sign]'
>   {-d,--decrypt}'[decrypt file or stdin]'
>   '(-c --symmetric)'{-c,--symmetric}'[encrypt with symmetric cipher only]'
36d35
<   '*:filename _files:_path_files -g "(#i)*.gpg(-.)"'
179c178
< _arguments -C -s -S -A "-*" $args $extra  && ret=0
---
> _arguments -C -s -S -A "-*" $args $extra '*:args:->args' && ret=0
```

Comment: thank you, that works nicely. I have another similar open question, and I have started a bounty. Would you perhaps be interested?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691306/zsh-completion-rules-for-custom-script

Answer (score 1):

`zstyle` can be used with `-e` for the value of the style to be evaluated at run time, so though there's likely to be a cleaner / neater way to do it, you can always do something like:

```
zstyle -e ':completion::complete:gpg:*' file-patterns '
  if (( ! words[(I)-*] || words[(I)-d] )); then
    reply=("*.(gpg|sig)(.)")
  elif (( words[(I)-[ec]] )); then
    reply=("^*.gpg(.)")
  fi'
```

That could be refined using `zparseopts` to handle calls like `gpg -ve` or `gpg --encrypt`...