# zsh completion rules for custom script

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have zsh completion file for custom script `foo`.

It should complete regular files in `$HOME/foo` :

```
#compdef foo

_arguments -S : \
    '-i' \
    '1:thing:_path_files -W $HOME/foo -g "*(.)"'
```

I need to modify the completion as follows:

Add optional parameter `--dir`.

When I type `foo --dir<TAB>`, it should offer completion for directories in `$HOME/foo`

```
foo --dir=<TAB>
```

And also, the file completion path (which is `$HOME/foo` by default) should change to `$HOME/foo/my_dir`, where `my_dir` is the name provided as `--dir=my_dir`.

## UPDATE:

Basically, the completion rule is supposed to have 2 modes of operation:

1. when I type `foo -<TAB>`, it is supposed to offer me optional parameters (`-d` `-w` `-l` `-i`). Then, depending on the optional parameter chosen:

1a) `foo -d <TAB>` completes only directories in the path

1b) `foo -w / -l / -i <TAB>` completes regular files in the path

this works as desired.

2. when I type `foo <TAB>`, the completion rule is supposed to offer regular files in the path. Currently, this does not work as desired. It still offers me the optional parameters, and I have to chose one, to then have directories/files completed.

When I type `foo <TAB>` (without the `-`), it only offers me the option parameters. Only after I have chosen one of the optional parameters, does my completion rule offer directories/files in the path.

How can I fix my script, so that it works without any optional parameters, and in such case simply completes regular files from the path ?

Here is the completion rule:

```
#compdef foo

local -A opt_args

_arguments -S -C \
    '-i[select file]:thing_file:_path_files -W $HOME/manuals/${opt_args[-d]} -g "*(.)"' \
    '-l[select file]:thing_file:_path_files -W $HOME/manuals/${opt_args[-d]} -g "*(.)"' \
    '-w[select file]:thing_file:_path_files -W $HOME/manuals/${opt_args[-d]} -g "*(.)"' \
    '-d[select directory]:directory_file:_path_files -/ -W $HOME/manuals' \
     && return 0
```

And one last small issue. The completion rule expects (completes) only one optional parameter.

When I type `foo -i -<TAB>` it does not offer other remaining optional parameters. These parameters should not be mutually exclusive. It should be possible to use:

```
foo -i -l -w <TAB>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like that:

```
#compdef foo

local -A opt_args

_arguments -S -C \
    '-i[select file]:thing_file:_path_files -W $HOME/foo/${opt_args[-d]} -g "*(.)"' \
    '-d[select directory]:directory_file:_path_files -/ -W $HOME/foo' \
     && return 0
```

To explain how it works functionally:

Create ~/foo:

```
mkdir ~/foo
```

Create 10 directories inside ~/foo:

```
mkdir ~/foo/DIR{1..10}
```

Create a file in the 4th directory:

```
$ touch ~/foo/DIR4/FILE4
```

And a file in ~/foo:

```
touch ~/foo/FILE-IN-FOO
```

Type

foo -d

and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It shows:

```
$foo -d DIR1/
DIR1/   DIR10/  DIR2/   DIR3/   DIR4/   DIR5/   DIR6/   DIR7/   DIR8/   DIR9/
```

Only directories are shown so no FILE-IN-FOO.

Select DIR4 and add -i:

```
foo -d DIR4 -i
```

and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It shows:

```
foo -d DIR4 -i FILE4
```

Comment: I have small problem with the completion rule. I have started a bounty. Would you please look, I have explained it in the UPDATE. Thank you.